# It gives me an error while I'm doing the integration test with the test containers in my reactive web spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testcontainers-junit5, spring-boot-testcontainers

`package com.example.demo4.controller;

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
//@WebFluxTest(UserController.class)  // Specify the controller class to test


@SpringBootTest(classes = UserController.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.demo4")
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@Testcontainers
public class ControllerIntegrationTest {


@Autowired
private WebTestClient webTestClient;

@MockBean
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Container
@ServiceConnection
public static MySQLContainer mySQLContainer  = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.2.0");



@Test
public void getAllUsers() {
    // Set up the database with some test data
    userRepository.saveAll(Flux.just(
            new User("1", "Alice", "alice@example.com"),
            new User("2", "Bob", "bob@example.com"),
            new User("3", "Charlie", "charlie@example.com")
    )).blockLast();

    // Act and Assert
    webTestClient.get().uri("/api/users")
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk()
            .expectHeader().contentType("application/json")
            .expectBodyList(User.class)
            .value(userList -> {
                StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(userList))
                        .expectNextCount(3)
                        .verifyComplete();
            });
}
```

}

`
this is my testclass. below I will add my service and the repository classes.

```
`package com.example.demo4.repository;

import com.example.demo4.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, String> {


}
```

`
###########################
Below is the service.

`

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final Map<String, User> userStorage = new HashMap<>();
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {

    this.userRepository = userRepository;

    // Initialize the userStorage map in the constructor
    User user1 = new User("1", "Alice", "alice@example.com");
    User user2 = new User("2", "Bob", "bob@example.com");
    User user3 = new User("3", "Charlie", "charlie@example.com");

    userStorage.put(user1.getId(), user1);
    userStorage.put(user2.getId(), user2);
    userStorage.put(user3.getId(), user3);
    }

    public Flux<User> getAllUsers() {
     return userRepository.findAll();

    }

    public Mono<User> getUserById(String id) {
        // return userRepository.findById(id);
        return Mono.justOrEmpty(userStorage.get(id));
    }

    public Mono<User> saveUser(User user) {
        // return userRepository.save(user);
         userStorage.put(user.getId(), user);
        return Mono.just(user);
    }

    public Mono<Void> deleteUser(String id) {
        // return userRepository.deleteById(id);
        userStorage.remove(id);
        return Mono.empty();
   }
}
```

`

So when I try running the above test case it gives me this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3xD5.png)

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@3c97f5e9 testClass = com.example.demo4.controller.ControllerIntegrationTest, locations = [], classes = [com.example.demo4.controller.UserController], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnectionContextCustomizer@ccbcc4be, [ImportsContextCustomizer@4583b617 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, @org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={}, basePackages={"com.example.demo4"}, excludeFilters={}, includeFilters={}, lazyInit=false, nameGenerator=org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator.class, resourcePattern="**/*.class", scopeResolver=org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationScopeMetadataResolver.class, scopedProxy=DEFAULT, useDefaultFilters=true, value={"com.example.demo4"}), org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@36c54a56, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@73386d72, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@22be8255, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@6034e75d, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@31be6b49, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@ec54a5c9, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@2d140a7, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@a8e610a5], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

```
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:143)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'connectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/r2dbc/ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration$PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.pool.ConnectionPool]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception with message: org/testcontainers/r2dbc/R2DBCDatabaseContainer
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:950)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [io.r2dbc.pool.ConnectionPool]: Factory method 'connectionFactory' threw exception with message: org/testcontainers/r2dbc/R2DBCDatabaseContainer
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)
... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testcontainers/r2dbc/R2DBCDatabaseContainer
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
at org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.r2dbc.MySqlR2dbcContainerConnectionDetailsFactory$MySqlR2dbcDatabaseContainerConnectionDetails.getConnectionFactoryOptions(MySqlR2dbcContainerConnectionDetailsFactory.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryOptionsInitializer.initialize(ConnectionFactoryOptionsInitializer.java:51)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.createConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.java:65)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.ConnectionFactoryConfigurations$PoolConfiguration$PooledConnectionFactoryConfiguration.connectionFactory(ConnectionFactoryConfigurations.java:97)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.testcontainers.r2dbc.R2DBCDatabaseContainer
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
... 71 more

Comment: You are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 in one class, don't do that. Remove `@RunWith` and make sure that the `@Test` annotation is from JUnit5 not JUnit4.